# Add field to Proxy class created with Javassist

Tags: java, javassist, bytecode-manipulation

I am creating a Proxy class using Javassist ProxyFactory with the following code:

```
ProxyFactory factory = new ProxyFactory();
factory.setSuperclass(entity.getClass());
factory.setInterfaces(new Class[] { MyCustomInterface.class });
.....
Class clazz = factory.createClass();
Object result = clazz.newInstance();
```

The problem is that I also need to add a field to the class. But if I do `CtClass proxy = ClassPool.getDefault().get(clazz.getName());` it gaves a `NotFoundException`

How can I add a field the class created with createClass? Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: It doesn’t seem to be intended to manipulate these proxy classes. There wouldn’t be any code using that field. If you want a non-trivial class, use a class factory.

Comment: Is the field gonna be used by methods exposed in your MyCustomInterface?

Comment: Exactly, the field will be used by the methods in MyCustomInterface. AFAIK java do not allows to declare instance field in interfaces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is based in your reply to my comment.

You can indeed use `MyCustomInterface` and your proxyClass to create sort of a [mixin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) in Java. But you'll still have to cast from proxy class to `MyCustomInterface` to be able to call the methods.

Let's get started.

## Creating your proxy

First you create your proxy has you already were doing:

```
 // this is the code you've already posted
 ProxyFactory factory = new ProxyFactory();
 factory.setSuperclass(entity.getClass());
 factory.setInterfaces(new Class[] { MyCustomInterface.class });
```

## Method handler: Doing the magic

Javassist proxies allow you to add a [MethodHandler](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/html/javassist/util/proxy/MethodHandler.html). It basically acts has a an InvocationHandler would in a regular Java Proxy, that means it works as a method interceptor.

The method handler will be your mixin! First you create a new MethodHandler with the custom field you actually want to add to the class, along with the entity object you've started proxying:

```
  public class CustomMethodHandler implements MethodHandler {

    private MyEntity objectBeingProxied;
    private MyFieldType myCustomField;

    public CustomMethodHandler(MyEntity entity) {
       this.objectBeingProxied = entity;
    }

    // code here with the implementation of MyCustomInterface
    // handling the entity and your customField

    public Object invoke(Object self, Method method, Method proceed, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
          String methodName = method.getName();

          if(methodNameFromMyCustomInterface(methodName)) {
            // handle methodCall internally: 
            // you can either do it by reflection
            // or if needed if/then/else to dispatch
            // to the correct method (*) 
          }else {
             // it's just a method from entity let them
             // go. Notice we're using proceed not method!

             proceed.invoke(objectBeingProxied,args);
          }
    }
  }
```

(*) Notice that even if I say in the comment to handle the call internally you can have the interface implementation in another place that isn't your method handler and just call it from here.

## Getting everything together

```
ProxyFactory factory = new ProxyFactory();
factory.setSuperclass(entity.getClass());
factory.setInterfaces(new Class[] { MyCustomInterface.class });
Class cls = factory.createClass();

// bind your newly methodHandler to your proxy
((javassist.util.proxy.Proxy) cls).setHandler(new CustomMethodHandler(entity));
EntityClass proxyEntity = cls.newInstance();
```

You should now be able to do `((MyCustomInterface)proxyEntity).someMethodFromTheInterface()` and let it be handled by your `CustomMethodHandler`

## Summing up

- You create a proxy using Proxy Factory from javassist
- You create your own MethodHandler class that can receive your proxied entity and the field you want to operate
- You bind the methodHandler to your proxy so you can delegate interface implementation

Keep in mind that these approach isn't perfect, being one of the short comings the code in Entity class cannot refer to the interface unless you first create the proxy.

If anything wasn't very clear for you, just comment and I'll do my best to clarify you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was a great idea.... Just to mention, MethodHandler is a interface, not a class, so I had to implements MethodHandler (not extends)

Comment: Hi Fernando, glad I could help! Sorry about the MethodHandler mismatch, I was writing it out of my head no compiler help there ;-) I'll edit the post to correct that detail.

Comment: If you could write all that stuff just out of your head, you are a genius (hopefully not a mad one)

Comment: @Fernando: I'm not a genius and even though some call me mad I usually disagree, I like to see myself as a creative person ;-) In my work I've already created tools that rely in Javassist and I also do a lot of JVM voodoo so this kind of thing you were asking is a bit of my daily work... That's why it was out of my head.

Comment: @pabrantes: I´m having one problem with `Hibernate Envers`, I have one database with older register, so when I try to see my log, it generates a erros because didn´t find the register, but debuggin in Eclipse, inside these objects, I found a method handler, and inside the id field with the long id number, so I want to know if it´s possible to get this field? I got the handler class in one object. But don´t know how to get the id field. I tryed with reflection but didn´t helped me.

Comment: @DiegoMacario: Hello Diego, maybe you should try to post the question for better help. For what I've understood you have an object that implements MethodHandler and has a field that you want t access, is that it? By reflection you should be able to get it, remember you don't want to go through MethodHandler but rather through the object's class (do a getClass()) and keep in mind that by reflection you might need to worry about getFields vs getDeclaredFields and hierarchy if exists.

Comment: @pabrantes thanks for your support, yes solved my problem. It was because `Hibernate Envers` was implemented in a database with older registers. But not as you suggested, because I can acess the proxy object by reflection, I didn´t know why, because a iterate in fields, methods and classes but nothing as I wanted. In this link is answered by me [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22896124/how-to-retrieve-audited-register-with-relationship-manytoone-using-hibernate-en). Obrigado!