# Can i intercept the jobExecution.getExecutionContext() method using spring-aop?

Tags: spring-batch, spring-aop

i have to intercept the **jobExecution.getExecutionContext()** method of  **org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution.java** class of Spring-Batch.

Here is the sample code.

**Spring-Customer.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd">
```

```
<bean id="jobExecution" class="org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution" >
</bean>
```

```
    <property name="target" ref="jobExecution" />

    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <value>customerAdvisor</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="customerAdvisor"
    class="org.springframework.aop.support.NameMatchMethodPointcutAdvisor">
    <property name="mappedName" value="getExecutionContext" />
    <property name="advice" ref="hijackAroundMethodBeanAdvice" />
</bean>

<!--<bean id="customerAdvisor"
    class="org.springframework.aop.support.RegexpMethodPointcutAdvisor">
    <property name="patterns">
        <list>
            <value>.*getExecutionContext.*</value>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="advice" ref="hijackAroundMethodBeanAdvice" />
</bean>

--><bean id="jobRepository"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="databaseType" value="mysql" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

<bean id="jobLauncher"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>

<!-- create job-meta tables automatically -->
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-mysql.sql" />
    <jdbc:script location="org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql" />
</jdbc:initialize-database>

<bean id="report" class="com.mkyong.model.Report" scope="prototype" />
<bean id="itemProcessor" class="com.mkyong.CustomItemProcessor" />

<batch:job id="helloWorldJob">
    <batch:step id="step1">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="cvsFileItemReader" writer="xmlItemWriter" processor="itemProcessor"
                commit-interval="10">
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<bean id="cvsFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">

    <property name="resource" value="classpath:cvs/input/report.csv" />

    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
            <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                    <property name="names" value="id,sales,qty,staffName,date" />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <bean class="com.mkyong.ReportFieldSetMapper" />

                <!-- if no data type conversion, use BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper to map by name
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
                    <property name="prototypeBeanName" value="report" />
                </bean>
                 -->
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>

</bean>

<bean id="xmlItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter">
    <property name="resource" value="file:xml/outputs/report.xml" />
    <property name="marshaller" ref="reportMarshaller" />
    <property name="rootTagName" value="report" />
</bean>

<bean id="reportMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>
            <value>com.mkyong.model.Report</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**HijackAroundMethod.java**

```
package com.mkyong.aop;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor;
import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation;

public class HijackAroundMethod implements MethodInterceptor
{
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) throws Throwable {

        System.out.println("Method name : " 
                + methodInvocation.getMethod().getName());
        System.out.println("Method arguments : " 
                + Arrays.toString(methodInvocation.getArguments()));

        //same with MethodBeforeAdvice
        System.out.println("HijackAroundMethod : Before method hijacked!");

        try{
            //proceed to original method call
            Object result = methodInvocation.proceed();

            //same with AfterReturningAdvice
            System.out.println("HijackAroundMethod : Before after hijacked!");

            return result;

        }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
            //same with ThrowsAdvice
            System.out.println("HijackAroundMethod : Throw exception hijacked!");
            throw e;
        }



    }

}
```

**App.java**

```
package com.mkyong;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] springConfig  = 
            {   
                "Spring-Customer.xml"
            };

        ApplicationContext context = 
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(springConfig);

        JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
        Job job = (Job) context.getBean("helloWorldJob");

        try {

            JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
            ExecutionContext executionContext = execution.getExecutionContext();
            executionContext.put("Test", "Test String");
            System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution.getStatus());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Done");

    }
}
```

So when the execution.getExecutionContext() method is called then it must call the invoke method in HijackAroundMethod class, but somehow it doesn't work like that.

Comment: I this this can't be done because JobExecution instances aren't created using spring container. You can try (just a try) to proxify JobExecution returned by jobLauncher.

Comment: Thanks, Luca Basso Ricci. Can you please give some example how to proxify JobExecution returned by JobLauncher?

Comment: jobexecution is a class,not interface so strandard java proxy won't work. check for cglib proxy or javassist (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460262/add-field-to-proxy-class-created-with-javassist)

Comment: Why do you need to hijack that method call?  What are you attempting to do?

Comment: Using jBehave we are getting Execution Context empty. Even if we are setting the parameters into execution context running job.  
**In Test File**
`jobLauncherTestUtils.setJob(job1);
JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(new JobParameters(parameters));
ExecutionContext jobExecutionContext = jobExecution.getExecutionContext();
jobExecutionContext.put("country", country);`  
**and in the job** :
`ExecutionContext jobExecutionContext = chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getExecutionContext();`